# HTTP POST method callbacks

Tags: web-services, http, post

I want to use this service [OnWebChange](http://www.onwebchange.com) to monitor when a website changes and change mine accordingly. It would notify me via a URL callback to my website URL with a HTTP POST method. Can somebody explain in general how do I "catch" those HTTP POST callbacks?

I guess I need to write/use a program on my server that would be always listening for those callbacks. I just need some guidance what tools to use.

Comment: Did your watch some tutorials on that site (http://onwebchange.com/documentation/video-tutorials) ?

Comment: This is the only tutorial they have and it does not talk about "catching" those  callbacks in it.

Comment: What's your server language?

Comment: Server language is PHP.